Dubbio su "ricordarselo"
Ho letto diverse volte la frase "Basta ricordarselo." e quel "ricordarselo" mi sembrava che fosse della forma impersonale, di "ricordarsi" + "lo". Però per me è strano questo uso, perché se la frase è impersonale, non deve essere "Basta che ce lo si ricordi"? Perché la forma impersonale di "ricordarsi" è "ci si ricorda". Mentre "ricordarselo" dovrebbe essere la terza persona singolare o plurale. Un esempio di contesto: "Questa però non è una brutta notizia per l’Italia perché siamo sempre stati un canale di comunicazione tra Europa e Oriente. Basta ricordarselo." Non so se va bene quel "ricordarselo", forse bisogna sostituirlo con "ricordarcelo", o "ce lo si ricordi", o "ricordarsene"?

Sul vocabolario Treccani puoi vedere che il verbo bastare usato in modo impersonale può essere seguito da un infinito, come in questo esempio:

Basta chiedere con buone maniere, si ottiene tutto ciò che si vuole.

Nota che è il verbo bastare quello che è usato in una forma impersonale: per questa regione è coniugato nella terza persona del singolare. Questo è precisamente quello che accade nell'espressione della tua domanda. Nel tuo caso, il verbo all'infinito è ricordarsi usato transititivamente, nel modo che è spiegato dalla consulenza linguistica dell'Accademia della Crusca:

è diffusa anche la costruzione transitiva ricordarsi qualcosa.

Su questo sito puoi trovare questo esempio:

Ti ricordi la maestra delle elementari?

Quindi, l'espressione della tua domanda sarebbe più o meno equivalente a

Basta ricordarsi qualcosa.

Il tuo esempio potrebbe rendersi così:

Questa però non è una brutta notizia per l’Italia perché siamo sempre stati un canale di comunicazione tra Europa e Oriente. Basta ricordarsi questo (cioè, quello che è espresso nella frase precedente).

Se usiamo il pronome lo per sostituire questo, allora si diventa se e dunque abbiamo

Basta ricordarselo.


Grazie! Hai risolto il mio dubbio!
